# Icon marker in R's plotGoogleMaps

Tags: r, plotgooglemaps

plotGoogleMap by default shows the paddle marker. I want to have a simple colored circle instead (where color is tied to the value of a variable in my data frame).If I use custom marker (by referencing a .jpg file path for iconmarker argument), I'm not able to make the color vary by value of the variable. Any ideas or leads are very much appreciated.

thanks